# Job fails in one database and not in another database, process is waiting PAGEIOLATCH in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have problems with a job that fails in one database and in another database if it runs correctly while on the same server, the process is suspended in the activity monitor as expected by PAGEIOLATCH in the SQL SERVER, when I see the job history log, it doesn't give a clear error, just that the step failed in a part of the SP run, 
the execution time is not more than 10 minutes
if you can help me, thanks.
error in the job history:

```
Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$1. ...14)
2020-04-22 13:00:00 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 0).....

......

*******INICIO S*...  The step failed.
```

Comment: Why did you omit almost the enitre error?

Comment: Because it is quite extensive and the error does not specify anything, what it shows is the process that the SP is doing, such as the information of an insert that it does until it reaches about half the SP and that The step failed.

Comment: I check the error that appears in the history, line by line and it is the execution of the SP, at each step it gives (error 0), until it reaches a point where it says that it fails. Being new here they won't let me attach anything either :(